# Rails 4: routing error under a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In routes.rb:

```
namespace :account do
  resource :groups
  resource :posts
end
```

But I got error when located `http://0.0.0.0:3000/account/groups` :

```
***Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for Account::GroupsController***
```

I checked `http://0.0.0.0:3000/rails/info/routes` and got:

````
```
account_groups_path          POST    /account/groups(.:format)   account/groups#create
new_account_groups_path      GET     /account/groups/new(.:format)   account/groups#new
edit_account_groups_path     GET     /account/groups/edit(.:format)  account/groups#edit
                             GET     /account/groups(.:format)   account/groups#show
                             PATCH   /account/groups(.:format)   account/groups#update
                             PUT     /account/groups(.:format)   account/groups#update
                             DELETE  /account/groups(.:format)   account/groups#destroy
```
````

Why account/groups not map to index method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to generate only `index` action then update your route file to restrict the routes created to just `index` as follows:

```
namespace :account do
  resource :groups, only: [ :index ]
  resource :posts
end
```

The problem however is your resource declaration, you're using **[singular resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)**, i.e. `resource :groups` and `resource :posts`.  What this does is map `/account/groups` to `account/groups#show` and `account/posts#show`.  Pluralizing `resource` will be a better solution:

```
namespace :account do
  resources :groups
  resources :posts
end
```

With this change, running `rake routes` should provide you the `index` action you are looking for.